# How to get immediate children of a 'term' parent id through 'get_terms'?

Tags: categories, terms

I have a category orientation as:

**Series (ID: 15) (root category)**

Under 'Series', the following sub-categories are present:

- Series A (Contains 0 posts)
- Series B (Contains 1
  post)
- Series C (Contains 0 posts)

How can I get the all three subcategories under the 'Series' category using '[get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)'?

I have used the following parameter structure sent as `$args` (*[term query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/)*) to `'get_terms'` with no result. It returns an empty array:

```
$arg['taxonomy'] = 'category';
$arg['hide_empty'] = 0;
$arg['parent'] = 15;
$arg['number'] => 0;
$arg['orderby'] = 'term_id';
$arg['order'] = 'ASC';
```

What am i doing wrong?

Please note that I want to achieve this through `'get_terms'` only so that I can use the same for other custom terms too.

Answer (score 0):

You've set `number` to `0`, so it will do as told and return 0 terms. Remove the number argument if you want all matching terms.